# Instatiate with Unity two objects of same interface in the same class

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a case where I need to instantiate for the same interface two different implementation that are both used in the same class.

```
public AutoMapperRegisterFactory(IRegisterAutoMapper registerAutoMapper , IRegisterAutoMapper registerAutoMapperMobile)
{
   m_RegisterAutoMapper = registerAutoMapper;
}
```

How would I go about of telling unity that the first `IRegisterAutoMapper` should be of type `RegisterAutoMapper` and the second of type `RegisterAutoMapperMobile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with multiple named mappings for IRegisterAutoMapper combined with an InjectionConstructor telling Unity what specific mappings to use for each argument.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IRegisterAutoMapper, RegisterAutoMapper>() //default
    .RegisterType<IRegisterAutoMapper, MobileRegisterAutoMapper>("Mobile")
    .RegisterType<AutoMapperRegisterFactory>(
        new InjectionConstructor(
            typeof(IRegisterAutoMapper), 
            new ResolvedParameter<IRegisterAutoMapper>("Mobile")));
```